# Troubleshooting mkvirtualenv on macosx 10.14.15

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew, mkdir, macos-mojave

I need some light here. I installed Python3 by running `brew install python3` and I got the return that everything was properly installed. I also installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper by running `sudo pip3 install virtual env virtualenvwrapper` (I know I shouldn't run it using sudo, but i needed to do it here). When I run the command I get the following:

```
WARNING: The directory '/Users/anarenault/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (16.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: stevedore in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper) (1.30.1)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper) (0.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper) (1.12.0)
```

But when I try to run `mkvirtualenv myapp`i get the following:
`zsh: command not found: mkvirtualenv`

I've already tried to export the path following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@gitudaniel/installing-virtualenvwrapper-for-python3-ad3dfea7c717, this tutorial https://gist.github.com/heymonkeyriot/9a2f429caff5c091d5429666fa080403, and this tutorial https://techstricks.com/mkvirtualenv-command-not-found-virtualenvwrapper/ and nothing works.

Also, when I run `/bin/bash --login`, I get the following:

```
bash: /path/to/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
bash: /Users/anarenault/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
bash: /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

Also, when I try to run `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`, I get the following:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

If you need me to provide more information, just ask! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I used de command: `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python`and it worked. Thanks!